# INOP parking brake on checkride

Tags: ppl, checkride, designated-examiner, exams

The ACS states that the applicant must secure the airplane and complete the appropriate checklist.  The checklist states to set the parking brake.

But what if the parking brake is inoperative?  What would be the appropriate action for securing the airplane on the checkride?  Carefully get out while ensuring the plane won't roll, and insert chocks ASAP?

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, if you can find relief for the inop parking brake in the Minimum Equipment List (if the aircraft has one) you can follow that to operate the airplane. However, since the ACS states (as you say in your question) that the ACS says to follow the checklist and the checklist "...states to set the parking brake." you may want to get it fixed before the checkride or talk to the examiner and see what would be acceptable to him before you schedule the check.

Comment: You might impress the examiner with situational awareness and utilization of resources by asking to hold the brakes while the plane is chocked and tied.